# Umbraco Request Lifecycle Diagram

Tags: c#, umbraco, diagram, lifecycle, umbraco6

I'm currently investigating performance issues with an Umbraco 6.1.6 website. The website is running a lot of custom code and I am certain this is the cause, however to better aid my understanding of the application, can someone provide a graphical diagram that explains the life cycle of a page request?

Specifically I would like to understand the process flow through each major part of the Umbraco application to returning the content including:

- Routing
- Where any database requests take place
- When caching is used and where it lives
- How traversing nodes in razor/c# works e.g. @CurrentPage.Descendants() / Ancestors()

I'm hoping this already exists, but I can't find it on the Umbraco forum.

Answer (score 5):

I cannot add a comment because I don't have 50 reputation, and its not the precise answer I can give you.. BUT, if you set **umbracoDebugMode** to true in web.config, you can then add **?umbdebug=true** to your url.

In the upper left corner you will get a small box that tells you how many ms the page took to render. Click on that, and you can see how many ms all the controls takes to render. Also, under Query time, you can click on the number, and then see all query's to the db.

Hope this help to debug your performance issue.

Comment: Morten, that's actually quite handy! Thanks